# Unable to trigger Click Even from List inside TileContainer SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a list inside Tile container.Direct list is working Okay, but inside the tile container I'm unable to trigger itemPress event. the code is as below

```
  <TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete">
    <CustomTile class="sapMTile customTile sapMPointer ">
        <ScrollContainer height="100%" width="100%" vertical="true" focusable="true">
            <l:VerticalLayout class=" sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
                <l:content>
                    <FlexBox>
                        <List items="{/activeRules}" headerText="" **itemPress="onActiveRulesListItemPress"** growing="true" growingThreshold="3">
                            <CustomListItem>
                                <HBox>
                                    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
                                        <Text class="flexTilebar" text="{name}"/>
                                        <FlexBox class="flexTilebar">
                                            <micro:StackedBarMicroChart size="Responsive" maxValue="{/maxNumberOfInvocztions}">
                                                <micro:bars>
                                                    <micro:StackedBarMicroChartBar valueColor="Neutral" value="{numberOfInvocations}"/>
                                                </micro:bars>
                                            </micro:StackedBarMicroChart>
                                        </FlexBox>
                                        <FlexBox class="flexTilebar">
                                            <micro:StackedBarMicroChart bars="{scheduledServiceInvocations}" maxValue="{/maxScheduleCount}" size="Responsive">
                                                <micro:bars>
                                                    <micro:StackedBarMicroChartBar value="{scheduleCount}"/>
                                                </micro:bars>
                                            </micro:StackedBarMicroChart>
                                        </FlexBox>
                                    </VBox>
                                </HBox>
                            </CustomListItem>
                        </List>
                    </FlexBox>
                </l:content>
            </l:VerticalLayout>
        </ScrollContainer>
    </CustomTile>
</TileContainer>
```

Comment: please specify by name, which event you are unable to trigger.

Comment: itemPress="onActiveRulesListItemPress"

Comment: try `selectionChange="onActiveRulesListItemPress" mode="SingleSelectMaster"` (inherited from `ListBase` https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ListBase/events )

Comment: if that doesn't work try `press="onActiveRulesListItemPress"` Because `CustomListItem` inherits from `ListItemBase`, which has no `itemPress` event. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ListItemBase/events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set type="Navigation" in customListItem Because CustomListItem inherits from ListItemBase

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `type` property in `CustomListItem` as its default value is Inactive.

See `ListBase` [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#event:itemPress):

> Fires when an item is pressed unless the item's type property is Inactive.

Comment: I've not set type property. for your example i just edit  <CustomListItem type="Navigation" > but it does't work.